# The name of the GUI widget?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, visual-web-gui

What is the name of the following GUI widget? I would like to use it in GWT.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of widget is usually known as a *carousel*. Sometimes people also call it a *slide show* or *slider*.

You can see a [demo](https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#carousel) of a GWT `MaterialCarousel`. By default it only shows one item at a time, but you can configure it to show multiple items as per your picture.

Answer (score 0):

The domino-kit ui framework also has a carousel.

https://demo.dominokit.org/components/carousel